# Show that there does not exist $g \in L^1[0,1]$ such that $\varphi (f) = \int fg\ d\mu.$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $0 \neq \varphi \in (L^{\infty} [0,1])^*$ such that $\varphi (f) = 0,$ for all $f \in C[0,1].$ The existence of such a $\varphi$ is guaranteed by Hahn-Banach theorem since $C[0,1]$ is not dense in $L^{\infty} [0,1].$ Show that there does not exist any $g \in L^{1} [0,1]$ such that $\varphi (f) = \int fg\ d\mu,$ for all $f \in L^{\infty} [0,1],$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

How do I prove that? Can anybody please give me some hint?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Idea: Can you approximate $g$ by continuous functions in some way?

Comment: Yes I can. Now how do I proceed @Henno Brandsma?

Answer (score 4):

Consider $\phi (e^{2\pi i nx})=\int e^{2\pi i nx} g(x)d\mu (x)$. [You can split this into real and imaginary parts if you don't want to use complex valued fuctions].  The hypothesis implies that all the Fourier coefficients of the intergable function $g$ are $0$. Hence $g=0$ a.e. which forces $\phi $ to be $0$.

Comment: Why $\int fg_n\ d\mu = 0\ $?

Comment: But $\varphi (g_n) = \int gg_n\ d\mu.$

Comment: @Phibetakappa I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are a trillion ways to do this. Here's one. Fix $x \in (0,1)$. For large $n \ge 1$, let $\phi_n = \frac{1}{2/n}1_{(x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n})}$. We can take a sequence of continuous functions $\{\phi_n^{(k)}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \phi_n^{(k)} = \phi_n$ pointwise (consider trapezoid looking things). Since $\int \phi_n^{(k)}gd\mu = 0$ for each $k$, we see that, by the dominated convergence theorem, $\int \phi_n g d\mu = 0$ for each $n$. Since $g(z) = \lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{2r}\int_{z-r}^{z+r} g(y)d\mu(y)$ almost all $z$, we conclude that $g(x) = 0$ for almost every $x$. Hence, $\phi \equiv 0$, a contradiction.